# my own NPM package not working command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, npm-package

If I don't install my own CLI globally, I can't run it with my keyword command. Only if I install the NPM package globally, the start works with my keyword. I would like to install it with the command suggested by NPM and then run it with keyword.

Visit my CLI: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetstack

Installation as globally it works, started with sweetstack.

```
npm i -g sweetstack
```

Installation as local not working.

```
npm i sweetstack
```

Comment: This is correct. There is nothing to fix. Install it globally. The only use-case for not installing globally is if you want to use your command using `npx` or inside `package.json` (eg, for `start` or `build` script etc.). If you don't want to install it globally but want to use it in the terminal use `npx` to execute your command - `npx sweetstack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is expected, if your inspect the `$PATH` environment variables of your shell, you'll see that only the directory containing the globally installed packages is present.

If you want to install your tool locally (which is a good practice), you then have to run it through `npx`.

The associated documentation page details what it does more clearly and it's relation to `npm exec` : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx

```
cd ./your-project
npm i sweetstack

npx sweetstack
```